# Trying to set up a dataSource on Spring for authorisation via MySQL - security beans not loading/autowired issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting this error

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'securityDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
```

and this one below

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'securityDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have supplied below my Java Config and Security config files.

Today I was working on implementing AuthenticationManagerBuilder with JDBC following a tutorial. I amended my DataSource bean to fit the one in tutorial and now I am getting this issue. Authentication worked fine before, so did DB connection and hibernate interactions.

Not sure where to even start looking now.

> Here is my Java config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"domain.applicationform","domain.config","domain.service","domain.dao"})
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class ConfigClass extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    //Var to hold props and converter for ints
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        int val = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        return val;
    }

    // logger
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    //ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource securityDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        try {
            securityDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        //logging
        logger.info(">>> jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info(">>> jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        securityDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));
        return securityDataSource;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        //properties     hibernateProperties.setProperty()

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(securityDataSource());
            //sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[] { EqualOps.class });
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                      new String[] { "domain.applicationform","domain.dao","domain.service","domain.config"});
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
              = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }

}
```

> Here is my SecurityConfig

```
package domain.config;


import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/manager/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
        .antMatchers("/management/recruitment/**").hasRole("RECRUITER")
        .antMatchers("/management/equalops/**").hasRole("RECRUITER")
        .antMatchers("/management/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/authenticationPage")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }
}
```

> EDIT1

My apologoies, forgot to post properties file.

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=root

connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000
```

Comment: can you post your application.properties file?

Comment: @slimane , post edited.

Comment: Are your logging messages printed when the application starts?

Comment: @akuma8 if I am, I am unaware of it. (could you elaborate what do you mean)

Comment: Just to know if the bean is really instantiated or not.

Comment: @akuma8, I assume, I need to enable Spring logging for this, perhaps you would have a link handy for eclipse? Will start my search now too.

Comment: Let me know when you'll see your logs. I use IntelliJ but It's not related to the IDE.

Comment: @akuma8, hey I still not sure what you meant. I added a System.out.println at the start of the method and nothing has printed? Is it this what you meant?

Comment: Yes that is! This means that your bean is not discovered.

Comment: I don't understand why or how I can solve this. I have been trying componentscan, import etc. but I am just taking stabs in the dark here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot `datasource` AutoConfiguration happens in application.properties. you need to specify the right properties in order to be recognized by spring.

try to use this:

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=
```

Here you can find common [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) supported by spring boot

Comment: Is that the same case for Spring MVC, because I am using spring-mvc?